# Microsoft Azure Database php while loop taking excess time. 19 rows, 3 columns taking 4 seconds

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, azure

```
    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $GamPlay = $row['GamesPlayed'];
    if(!in_array($GamPlay, $GamesPlayedArray)) {
        array_push($GamesPlayedArray,$GamPlay);
    $date = $row['Datetime'];

    $date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $currentdate = strtotime("now");




        $timesince = $currentdate - strtotime($date);

        if($timesince<86400) {
            $hourssince = round($timesince/3600);
            array_push($ListGamesArray,$hourssince . " Hours Ago",$row['UniqueNum']);
        } else {
            $jahf = $timesince/86400;
            $dayssince = floor($jahf);
            $hourssince = round(($jahf-$dayssince)*24);
            array_push($ListGamesArray,$dayssince . " Days " . $hourssince . " Hours Ago",$row['UniqueNum']);
        }


}
}`
```

The SQL query itself takes zero time, but when executing this bit of code it takes 4 seconds when there is only 19 rows and 3 columns.

Any help appreciated!`

Comment: you've given no information about where you hosted your code (e.g. web app?), size of VM/service, whether your database and code are in the same region, whether you're running SQL Server in a VM (you tagged it as [tag:sql-server]) or SQL Database service (and if so, what performance tier)... Please edit your question with more details. Otherwise, there's really nothing to help with...

Answer (score 0):

@David,
According to your description, we can not easy to defined your service scope. But from my experience, I recommend you can pay attention to these points:
If you used SQL Server on Azure VM, you need check:

1. VM Size. You could scale your VM.

2.Storage, use the Premium storage. And keep your storage account and SQL server VM in same region.

3. Disk, Use a minimum of 2 P30 Disks.
4. I/O,Enable database page compression,Enable instant file initialization for data files,Limit or disable autogrow on the database,Disable autoshrink on the database.

For more information, please refer to this document :https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sql-performance/

If you use SQL Azure service, You may need to change the service tiers. Please see this documents about SQL Azure database.https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-performance-guidance/